# FlatBuffers: Unsupported vectors of unions error converting JSON file to binary file

Tags: c++, json, compiler-errors, schema, flatbuffers

I created a schema containing arrays of unions and I was able to generate C++ source for this schema. As I understand JSON data based on the FBS schema can be converted into binary data to be used as input for C++ application. Thus I wanted generating a binary file from a JSON file. I created a JSON file trying to follow the schema but the conversion failed with

> error: Vectors of unions are not yet supported in all the specified
>   programming languages.

using

> flatc -b schema.fbs data.json

How could the binary file be created from JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, this feature has been implemented only for the C++ generator (yes, JSON and binary count as "programming language" in the way `flatc` organizes things).

Comment: Thanks. I suspected this would be the answer but JSON isn't a programming language. It would be nice to have a feature creating a sample JSON file from the schema containing all the elements defined in the schema - something similar to Visual Studio that allows generating a XML sample from a XSD.